# Azure webjob image resize issue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am using azure web job to save thumb of an image   and this is  code for doing this

```
ImageProcessor.Imaging.Formats.FormatBase f;
f = new ImageProcessor.Imaging.Formats.JpegFormat();


Size size = new Size(200, 200); 
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(input));
                MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
                int quality = 110;


                do
                {
                    quality = quality - 10;
                    using (ImageFactory factory = new ImageFactory(false))
                    {
                        factory.Load(stream)
                            .Format(f)
                            .Resize(size)                          
                            //.BackgroundColor(Color.White)
                            .Quality(quality)
                            .Save(stream2);
                    }
                } while (stream2.Length > stream.Length || stream2.Length ==100000);
```

When i add message to queue with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuGVK.jpg) image for example, 
job should give me thumb image 200 * 200 but there is trailing black area in top and bottom of resulted image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHmfd.jpg) which shouldn't be done 
Why this is done ???

Comment: Could it be that the source image isn't square but you are trying to fit it into square dimensions and the function is attempting to keep the original aspect ratio?

Comment: Your image is 500x375. Not sure how you'd expect a 200x200 thumbnail to be properly generated without any type of bars. In any case: This isn't a database issue (and doesn't really seem to be a programming issue either).

Comment: @DavidMakogon sorry header is wrote by mistake

Comment: @DavidMakogon what do mean by bars ??

Comment: @Moustafa I'm talking about the "trailing black area" you mentioned. Or... black bars, as they are typically referred to.

Comment: @DavidMakogon so if i want to resize it to 200*200 without get this trailing black area how i do that ??
should i use scaling forexample ??

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum - please don't continue asking additional questions in comments. I already pointed you in the right direction by pointing out your core issue.

Comment: I didn't mean to give me exact answer i want just hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to fit a rectangle into a square.

From http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/resize/:

> #### Resize
>
> Resizes the current image to the given dimensions. If EXIF metadata is to be preserved the information contained within will also be updated to match.
>
> `public ImageFactory Resize(Size size)`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *size*:
>
> The `System.Drawing.Size` containing the width and height to set the image to.
>   **Passing a 0 for either dimension will omit that dimension.**

So, pass in `0` as height to maintain aspect ratio,

```cs
Size size = new Size(200, 0);
```

or use one of the other resize modes: **Crop/Min/Max/Stretch**

Comment: Thanks very much for detailed answer :)